# Jquery Change value on multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scope

I want to count the checkbox checked and words in textbox and make a new variable out of both.

**What I have done is:**
Both Work separately. 
I want to access *len* variable in the textbox event and then sum the current ammount + checkbox checked.

```
<h2>Moods</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mood[]">Optimistic
        <input type="checkbox" name="mood[]">Cheerfull

    <textarea id="readscript" cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Read Text here" required></textarea>
```

Here is the jsfiddle explaining and showing what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/wqoynasu/5/

Thanks!!

Comment: Please add the essential code of your fiddle to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following snippets to your code.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
        $('#readscript').trigger('input');
    });
```

and inside the on- input event of readscript use the following.

```
if (c.words == 0) {
          $ammount = 0 + $("input[name='mood[]']:checked").length;
            $price.html($ammount);
        }
        if (c.words <= 80) {
          $ammount = 10 + $("input[name='mood[]']:checked").length;
            $price.html($ammount);
        }
        if (c.words > 80 && c.words <= 200) {
        $ammount = 15 + $("input[name='mood[]']:checked").length;
            $price.html($ammount);
        }
        if (c.words > 300 && c.words <= 400) {
          $ammount = 20 + $("input[name='mood[]']:checked").length;
            $price.html($ammount);
        }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Ananthaprakash Thanks for your reply, I tried this but nothing is happening. The price remains zero in every case. can you please edit or create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Thanks @Ananthaprakash, Gave it another try and it is exactly what I was expecting :) Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you simply calculate len in the textbox change event again. There is no need to update a global variable. You can always retrieve it like this when you need it:

```
var len =  $("input[name='mood[]']:checked").length;
```

or you wrap this code in a function `numberOfCheckedCheckboxes()`.

There is also an error in your script. The first of the cascade of `if`s always falls through to the second (0 is always <= 80). Use `else if` after the first if.

**Update:** I recommend you create one `update()` function that does both parts of the calculation and is triggered if either text or checkboxes change.

Comment: Hi @lex82, Thanks for your reply. I also thought this but I think this is not good approach, What if user write the text first and then check the checkboxes ?

Comment: I recommend you create one update() function that does both parts of the calculation and is triggered if either text or checkboxes change.

Comment: Thanks. I got this. I am not so good in Jquery. I understand the logic you are talking about. Can you give a little example?

Comment: Well, I assume you can write basic Javascript functions. So write one called numberOfCheckedCheckboxes() as suggested. Write another one called updatePrice() that contains the current price calculation and uses the first function. Then call updatePrice() when the checkbox changes or when the input changes. I.e. call it from both event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event handler for all kinds of your inputs, check its type then pass it to your functions accordingly.

```
$('input, textarea').change(function(event){
   alert(event.target.type) // This checks the input type
})
```

Comment: Hi @itzhak I tried this. Nothings happens. No alert comes I removed all the code and did this. Still no alert.

Comment: Hi @Abrar, I added another answer which works, Checked it :) Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong cause change event runs on textarea only when unfocus. I think the best solution is using two event handlers send them to your function -

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(event){
     yourFunc();
});

$('input').change(function(event){
     yourFunc();
});
```